# Solrj: how to specify path

Tags: autocomplete, solr, autosuggest, solrj

I'm trying to use the [TermsComponent](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/TermsComponent) to implement autosuggest with Solrj, but I don't see how to specify the path (i.e. the `/terms` portion of `http://localhost:8983/solr/terms`).

How can I specify the path using Solrj?

Bonus: is there a way to specify multiple fields for the `terms.fl` param?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here we go:

```
    SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
    query.setParam(CommonParams.QT, "/terms");
    query.setParam(TermsParams.TERMS, true);
    query.setParam(TermsParams.TERMS_LIMIT, "10");
    query.setParam(TermsParams.TERMS_FIELD, "title", "description");  // or whatever fields you want
    query.setParam(TermsParams.TERMS_PREFIX_STR, typedInput);
```

This is assuming that you have the TermsComponent wired in at "/terms"; the default solrconfig.xml has it there.

And for the bonus: you can add multiple fields simply by adding multiple strings for `TERMS_FIELD` (or multiple URL `&terms.fl=foo` params).

Thank you Mauricio, for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Direct support for TermsComponent is not available in SolrJ 1.4.1, but take a look at the [corresponding patch](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1139), it's pretty easy to implement it yourself.

Since TermsComponent is a standard component you don't need to use /terms, you can [hook it to the standard query request handler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SearchComponent).

Comment: Hi Mauricio. I have the TermsComponent working just fine in my solr server- I can query it with urls like "http://localhost:8983/solr/terms?terms.fl=description&terms.sort=count&terms.prefix=foo". The problem is that I don't know how to generate such URLs via solrj client requests. The urls always have "solr/select", and I suspect I need them to have "solr/terms". Am I missing something?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Caffeine Coma: you don't need /solr/terms. Hook up the TermsComponent to the standard search handler. See the second link I posted in my answer.

Comment: TermsComponent was already hooked up in my solrconfig.xml; I just didn't know how to properly specify it in solrj. I needed to add "/terms" as the argument for the "qt" parameter. Sorry for so many dumb questions, but the documentation is a little thin. Thanks very much for your help Mauricio.

Answer (score 2):

I spend so much time to make the TermsComponent work.

At the end of the day, I realized that there is a different set of commands that you need to invoke in order to retrieve the results from the "/terms" requestHandler.

I was trying to get the results using

```
HttpSolrServer server = new HttpSolrServ(solrUrl);
List<SolrDocument> list = server.query(query).getResults()
```

However, the correct way to get the results from the TermsComponent is

```
HttpSolrServer server = new HttpSolrServ(solrUrl);
TermsResponse termResp = server.query(query).getTermsResponse();
List<Term> tList = termResp.getTerms("fieldNAME");
```

I hope this may help someone else in the future.